# How to implement array of int, string, float and date object using c++ Template?

Tags: c++, templates

Write a program that creates and displays arrays of integers, floats, strings, and Date objects (where Date objects model a date using integer month, day, year attributes) using Class Template.

I was able to display arrays of integers, floats and string but having problems with Arrays of the Date object. I'm not sure how to call the print date function (in Date class) from the template class.

```
template< typename T > 
class Myarray {

private:
    int size;
    T *myarray;
public:
    // constructor with user pre-defined size
    Myarray(int s , T* array) {
        size = s;
        myarray = new T[size];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            myarray[i] = array[i]; // Copy into object
        }

    }
    // calss array member function to set element of myarray 
    // with type T values
    void setArray(int elem, T val) {
        myarray[elem] = val;
    }

    // for loop to display all elements of an array
    void getArray() {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            // typeid will retriev a type for each value
            cout << setw(7) << j << setw(13) << myarray[j] <<endl;
        }
        cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    }

};

class Date {
private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
public:
    Date() {
        day = month = year = 0;
    }
    Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        this->day = day;
        this->month = month;
        this->year = year;

    }

    void print_date(void) {
        cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl;
    }


};

int main()
{
    // instantiate int_array object of class array<int> with size 2
    int array1[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    Myarray< int > int_array(5,array1);
    int_array.getArray();


    float array2[] = { 1.012, 2.324, 3.141, 4.221, 5.327 };
    Myarray<float> b(5, array2);
    b.getArray();


    std::string array3[] = { "Ch1","Ch2","Ch3","Ch4","Ch5" };
    Myarray<std::string> c(5, array3);
    c.getArray();


    Date array4[] = { Date(10, 18, 2019), Date(1, 01, 2019), Date(7, 04, 2019),
                    Date(12, 31, 2019), Date(12, 25, 2019) };
    Myarray<Date> d(5, array4);
    d.getArray();



    return 0;
}
```

Getting Error message:

```
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Date'
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your `getArray` function, which is calling `<<` on `myarray` which is of type `T`:

```
cout << setw(7) << j << setw(13) << myarray[j] <<endl;
```

Here, it expects that `myarray[j]` can be called with `operator<<` which is true for `int`, `float` and `std::string`, but your `Date` class does not provide an `operator<<` to use, how would it know how it should be output? It won't know to call `print_date`. Instead, you should just provide an `operator<<` in `Date`:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& oss, const Date& d)
{
    oss << d.day << "/" << d.month << "/" << d.year << "\n";
    return oss;
}
```

Now you can write things like:

```
Date d;
std::cout << d;
```

And similarly it can be used by your `MyArray` class.